# How do I get the UUID of a bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I need to know UUID on API 8 (2.2) or possibly 2.3.3.

As I understand the documentation, this should be allowed:

```
    phoneDevice = blueAdapter.getRemoteDevice(phoneAddress);
    ParcelUuid[] phoneUuids = phoneDevice.getUuids();  // Won't compile
```

Eclipse gives me:
*"The method getUuids() is undefined for the type BluetoothDevice."*
But see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()

Also, I would like to know how the UUIDs are "parceled" inside the ParcelUuid[]. In case I ever manage to get there, how do I retrieve a UUID from a parcelUuid[]? Documentation for Android bluetooth seems to be very poor, in my opinion.

What a joke!
Now I try to get it from the intent, but this too gives: *"EXTRA_UUID cannot be resolved or is not a field"*:

```
intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
```

Comment: this will support from API level 15. whats your API level?

Comment: Hi facing same problem , in my project have provide support from android 2.3.1 , min api level 8. Please help.

Comment: Hi. Long time passed fro this post but I am now facing this exact same issue. Do you have any workaround for that (my minimum API is 10) ?Thanks for any clue

Answer (score 5):

You have to use reflection to use the getUuids() and fetchUuidsWithSdp() on android version < 3. So, try the code:

```
Method method = phoneDevice.getClass().getMethod("getUuids", null);
ParcelUuid[] phoneUuids = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(phoneDevice, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

//this will support from API level 15 and above.

```
Broadcast Action: This intent is used to broadcast the UUID wrapped as a ParcelUuid of the remote device after it has been fetched. This intent is sent only when the UUIDs of the remote device are requested to be fetched using Service Discovery Protocol
    Always contains the extra field EXTRA_DEVICE
    Always contains the extra field EXTRA_UUID
    Requires BLUETOOTH to receive.
    Constant Value: "android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID"
```

//no way to degrade its hardware related. there is no supporting jar also. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Okay, but API 15 is 4.0.3 released only a month ago. I need to use bluetooth on 2.2 API 8!

Comment: So, the way to do it is to create UUIDs? It's not a property of the hardware, it's just a number I make up, is that right?

Comment: @Tombola you able to get the uuid for android 2.2 to connect another device? post your solution here

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any good way to get the UUID's supported by a BluetoothDevice with API level < 15.  I guess that's why they added the new functions in API 15.

Note, from the [docs for BluetoothClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html)

> BluetoothClass is useful as a hint to roughly describe a device (for
>   example to show an icon in the UI), but does not reliably describe
>   which Bluetooth profiles or services are actually supported by a
>   device. Accurate service discovery is done through SDP requests, which
>   are automatically performed when creating an RFCOMM socket with
>   createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID) and
>   listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID).

So, perhaps the device class could be used as a hint as to what services will be available until you perform one of the listed functions.  Certainly it doesn't hurt to check the class since this won't require any additional bluetooth operations.

Note that the service class is also available (it is part of the device class) but this is just a general class, not a listing of specific services (like from SDP).

Answer (score 0):

try BluetoothAdapter class

any question, read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you can not get UUID from `getUuids()` method. Please try the other way.

After scanned successfully, you should receive `byte[]` (scanRecord), so from this result, if you can recognize `UUID format` you can split step by step to get correct UUID as these codes.

P/s : Important thing, you should know `UUID format` to get from index correctly.

```
// Put item into hash map
    // UUID from index 10 to 24 : 12233445566778899aabbccddeeff0
    StringBuilder mSbUUID = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < scanRecord.length; i++) {
        // UUID
        if (i >= 10 & i <= 24) {
            if (Integer.toHexString(
                    scanRecord[i]).contains("ffffff")) {
                mSbUUID.append(Integer.toHexString(scanRecord[i]).replace("ffffff", "") + "-");
            } else {
                mSbUUID.append(Integer.toHexString(scanRecord[i]) + "-");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is from '12, and ScanRecord is part of the newer Bluetooth LE API's. This question is geared for Bluetooth Classic.