# How can I discover the UUID from my android device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid

I'm trying to make an application that sends messages via Bluetooth. But when i try to connect my device with others an error occurs (my socket fails to make the connection and an exception is thrown. 
I honestly believe it's because of my UUID. I can't seem to find how to use it, so I have definied a static, already known value, that I found on the internet for my UUID. 
PS: I'm working with Android 2.3.7 (API 10), so the method getUuid() does not work.

Comment: Could you post the logs for the exception it throws when the connection fails?

Comment: Which UUID? Typically there are many. What exact purpose do you plan to use it for?

Answer (score 0):

For , android version < 3. So, try the code:

```
Method method = phoneDevice.getClass().getMethod("getUuids", null);
ParcelUuid[] phoneUuids = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(phoneDevice, null);
```

Hope it helps you..

Ref : [How do I get the UUID of a bluetooth device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568084/how-do-i-get-the-uuid-of-a-bluetooth-device)

Comment: The question you link asks how to obtainin the UUIDs of **remote** devices, while this question is about that of the phone itself.